# How to programmatically retrieve SharePoint My-Sites users' blog posts using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, blogs, mysite

I managed to access user profile content:

```
    using (SPSite ospSite = new SPSite("http://localhost:80/"))
    {
        ServerContext s = ServerContext.GetContext(ospSite);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(s);
        UserProfile p = profileManager.GetUserProfile("some_user");

        // e.g. responsibility retrieval
        var r = p["SPS-Responsibility"];
        var responsibilities = r.GetTaxonomyTerms();
    }
```

But I don't know how to access users' blog posts collection.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `PersonalSite` property of `UserProfile` object to retrieve the user's My Site.

In the SPSite loop through, child SPWeb objects which are of template "Blog". Check out the templates names here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richin/archive/2011/07/04/sharepoint-2010-site-template-names.aspx

Once  you find the blog site, you can simply access the items in "Posts" List of the SPWeb object.

Comment: As soon as I'm trying to iterate through child SPWeb objects by: `profile.PersonalSite.OpenWeb().Webs` or `profile.PersonalSite.AllWebs` I'm getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` exception even though I'm running the process as Administrator. Any advice?

Comment: Just found the solution, just need to execute it with elevated privileges: `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => { _some.code.here_ });`